# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user user@localhost

Tags: pdo

Имеем код:

```
$this->db = new PDO('mysql: host=195.210.46.56;port=3306;dbname=expertc3_jobsite','user','pass');
```

Подключение не идет потому, что PDO обращается к user по localhost, а нужно чтобы он подключался по `user@192.210.46.56`.

Как это исправить?

Comment: а вы уверены, что пользователю user есть доступ к mysql по адресу 192.210.46.56 ?

Comment: Да есть. Проблема исправлена. Нужно было писать доменное имя а не голый ip проблема исчезла